# SSH freeze when connecting to AWS

Tags: shell, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Connecting to Ubuntu 14.04 server at AWS gx2.2 instance(Huge GPU one), from an Ubuntu 14.04 system with the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@12.121.12.321
```

Normally it would just connect, but now it times out with this error:

```
ssh: connect to host 54.171.53.164 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can Ctrl+C out of the freeze though.
I have tried to restart.
I have tried to `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your AWS parameters...

1) Check Public Ip associated with the Amazon ec2 instance, check whether it is the same as ip address 12.121.12.321 you are using to make connection.

2) Check the inbound rule of the security group associated with the Amazon ec2 instance. Ensure that the inbound rule has ssh access to the ip address of the machine from which you are trying to connect the Amazon ec2 instance.

3) Ensure that the pem file you file you are using is appropriate.

Hope it helps...